# see variable definition by tooltips in vim

Tags: unix, vim, vi

I need to frequently check definitions of variables/functions. I can jump to definitions of variables/functions by ctags with `gd`,`gD`, `ctrl ]` etc.

But by it, I jump from my current position and lose context of current position. Is there any way I can check definitions in tool tips like we see in `ctrl p` `ctrl n` in insert mode. It would really help in quickly understand and browsing code.

Thanks,

Comment: `gd` gD and `Ctrl-]` all of them modify the jump list. So you can go back to your previous position with `C-o` or use `gi` to go back to last edit position and start insert mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you already have an up-to-date and reachable `tags` file, you can see the definition of the variable or method under your cursor *in a preview window* with:

```
<C-w>}
```

See `:h preview-window`.